# TabHost not showing contents in the beginning

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have a TabActivity with two tabs. the layout of the activity is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

The layout consists of a ListView which is populated accordingly in setOnTabChangedListener(). no problem with filling the list and showing it.

My problem is that the list view is not shown when the activity starts, although I find it by ID and populate it; it is only populated after I change the tabs.

and the code in the onCreate(..) looks like this:

```
l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
l.setAdapter(new CommentsAdapter(this, (JSONArray) obj));

TabSpec spec;
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("0").setIndicator("0",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_recent)).setContent(
            R.id.list);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("1").setIndicator("1",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_pop)).setContent(
            R.id.list);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int tab = Integer.valueOf(tabId);
            showDialog(WAIT_DIALOG);

            switch (tab) {
            // recent
            case 0:
                //refill the list
                break;
            // popular

            case 1:
                //refill the list
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

any hints?

Comment: it is possible to put all the codes of tab so that we can have look & tell

Comment: just put java code & nt XML coz u r XML might be fine ontab change list view is display

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue. What I noticed is that if you do

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

then `onTabChanged` is not triggered. BUT, if you do

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
```

then it is, the list shows up and all it's fine. As per why this happens, it remains a bit of a mistery to me.

Use this cheat to start your app on the first tab:
in onCreate(), after you've created the tabs call first:
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
Then call:
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

Comment: This may work if my second tab didnt try to update its content before the the first is executed, `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created`

Comment: @MikeFlynn without a little more context I'm not sure how to reply

Comment: I am facing this problem, did anyone get a solution even after 5 years?

Answer (score 1):

You can try use different layout, say

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("0").setIndicator("0",
        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_recent)).setContent(
        R.id.list1);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("1").setIndicator("1",
        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_pop)).setContent(
        R.id.list2);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score -2):

you just do another activity in which list view is present & put the below one

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(tabs.this,listDisplay.class);
spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("0").setIndicator("0",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.                        tab_recent)).setContent(i1);
```

Also put the `tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);`
before `ontabChangeListener` Hope this might help..

hope this might solve the problem..

Comment: I dont want to use a separate activity @Sumant. the solution is ineffective.